# Add a darkening filter to an image OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I apologize in advance if a question like this was already answered. All of my searches for adding filters resulted in how to add dog faces. I wasn't sure what the proper terminology is.

What techniques do phone apps (such as Snapchat's text overlay or a QR code program for android) use to "darken" a section of the image? I am looking to replace this functionality in OpenCV. Is it possible to do this with other colors? (Such as adding a blue accent)

Example: Snapchat text overlay

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlSnS.jpg

Another Example: Google Allo QR code search

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sl1B.jpg

Any questions or comments would be appreciated

Comment: Both of those examples look to me like results of alpha blending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I was able to darken an image by blending an image matrix with a black matrix. After that, it was just a matter of darkening certain parts of the image to replicate an overlay.

The lower the alpha value is, the darker the image.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOybu.jpg)

```
void ApplyFilter(cv::Mat &inFrame, cv::Mat &outFrame, double alpha)
{
    cv::Mat black = cv::Mat(inFrame.rows, inFrame.cols, inFrame.type(), 0.0);
    double beta = (1.0 - alpha);
    cv::addWeighted(inFrame, alpha, black, beta, 0.0, outFrame);
}
```

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html

Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 6):

**In General:**
Change of brightness can be achieved via Addition/Subtraction.
If you want to brighten your Image, you can add a specific amount (e.g. 20) to each channel of the image. The other way around for darkening (Subtraction).

If you would subtract 50 from each channel of the image, you would get:
[image: Subtraction 50]

To darken pixel dependent you could also use Division. This is how a division with 1.5 would change the image:
[image: Division]

Another way would be to use the [Exponential Operator](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/pixexp.htm). This operator takes the value of each channel and will then calculate pixel^value. The resulting value will be then scaled back to the 0-255 range (for 8 bit RGB) via looking the highest value and then calculating the scaling factor via 255/resulting value.

If use it with values > one, it will darker the image. This is because 
Here a chart how the exponential operator will change the value of each pixel. As you can see, values for the operator above 1 will darken the image (meaning the channels will be shifted towards lower values), whilst values below 0 will shift all pixels towards white and thus increase brightness.
[image: Power Operator explanatory chart]

Here is an example image for application of the operator using the value 0.5, meaning you take each pixel^0.5 and scale it back to the range of 0-255:
[image: Exponential Operator 0.5]
For a value of 2 you get:
[image: Exponential Operator 2]

Sadly i can not help you further, because i am not familiar with OpenCV, but it should be easy enough to implement yourself.

For your question about tinting: Yes, that is also possible. Instead of shifting towards white, you would have to shift the values of each pixel towards the respective color. I recommend to [inform you about blending](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/blend.htm).

[Original image taken from here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum)